# Prove that $\operatorname{Homeo}(\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group with the compact open topology.

Tags: general-topology

I already prove that if $X$ is Hausdorff and compact space $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ is a topological group.
Now I think that it result is a colorally of the proposition of above, the problem is that $X=\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff but not compact, hence it makes me think that we can prove a similar result with local compact spaces.
Any suggestion for how do I should apply the result to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Any group can be topologized for instance, giving it the discrete or trivial topology. But you want to do it so that the group operation, composition, is continuous. If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff, then the composition is indeed continuous, if Homeo$(X)$ is given the compact-open topology. [Munkres](https://www.amazon.com.mx/Topology-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292) has a very readable proof of this fact. So the answer is yes.

Comment: I tried to prove that inversion was continuous, and I think that the fact that real homeomorphisms are monotone must give you an answer somehow, but I couldn't get this to work. I found [this article](http://www.few.vu.nl/~dijkstra/research/papers/2005compactopen.pdf) which proves this for locally connected, locally compact Hausdorff, spaces by way of the one point compactification. By the way, I proved a general form of the continuity of composition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042542/prove-that-the-map-mcy-z-times-cx-y-rightarrow-cx-z-is-continuous/4042640#4042640).

Comment: @Matematleta The issue is whether *inversion* is also continuous, and that's a subtle matter. It's true in the case of $\Bbb R$ though.